# Why can I not use a variable to store echo() like I can other functions?

Tags: php, variables

I'm just trying to figure out why I can't do this:

```
<?php
$a = "echo";
$a("test");
?>
```

It just returns `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function echo() in Command line code on line 1`

When I can do this:

```
<?php
$a = "explode";
var_dump($a("|","1|2|3"));
?>
```

and get the expected result.

**Edit:** Found a solution to my problem (as inspired by the various answers below).
Create an anonymous function inside the variable $a as so:

```
$a = function($a){echo $a;};
```

This will only work in PHP 5.3 or greater though.

Comment: echo() is not actually a function it is a language construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>That's because [echo is not a function but a language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).</del>

<del>Try with `print()` instead. That should work fine.</del>

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments print is also a language construct and won't work! Only solution is wrapping echo or print in a user defined function then.

```
<?php
function output($str){ 
    return print $str;
}

$a = "output";
$a("Lorem Ipsum ...");
?>
```

Comment: `print` is also a language construct

Comment: Indeed it is! Yet print returns a value while echo doesn't, that might have me confused. My bad!

Comment: @Phil: Was doing just that while you replied :)

Comment: Figured out a better way to do this, if anyone is interested:
`$a = function($a){echo $a;};`

Comment: @Ben: sure, edit your question with the solution, it might just help someone else who stumbles across this page! Sharing is caring :)

Answer (score 2):

Echo isn't a function.  It's a language construct that resembles a function but it doesn't return any values.  Because of this, it cannot be used in variable functions (`$foo = 'echo'; $foo ('hello world');` doesn't work)

You will have to use a different output method from echo (such as print) to do what you want.

Comment: As stated elsewhere in my response, print doesn't work either. You'll have to resort to you own user defined method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because explode is a function whereas echo is a language construct. Notice there are no brackets when using echo.

Comment: You may actually use brackets with echo.

Answer (score 0):

Because echo is not a function, it is a built in part of PHP. 
See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

look in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo() (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo(), the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses.